# Can't convert System.Collections.Generic.List in List<>

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dreamfactory

I am trying to get a JSON from a API using Dreamfactory on Xamarin.Forms project. I was trying before with their API .net but it doesn't work for my cross-platform so I decided to try it with the TODORest Example they got in [1]: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo/Todo

I changed the URL to my API one and use the user like empty string and the password  for my API key . But when I return the Item to await RefreshDataAsync() tell me a error `CS0029 and CS4033` last error means await cant be used in a static but is a async method: `public static async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync().`

Can someone help me to find another way to connect to Dreamfactory API or why xamarin give me that errors from the xamarin sample?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please correct the formatting, it is very hard to spot your code and understand the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think there's a couple of things that could be improved with your question. First; readability. Use returns, formatting, etc. Second; please show some effort. What have you tried? Where did you fail? Stack Overflow is not for just simple problem solving or code as a service. Please refer to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide on how to formulate a proper question.